# Объединение датафреймов разной длинны

Tags: r, rstudio

[image: example]У меня есть два датафрейма с разным количеством строк. В первом столбце условный индекс наблюдения, а во втором значение наблюдения. Мне необходимо объединить эти два датафрейма в один по их индексам, и если в каком либо из датафреймов нет наблюдения с таким индексом как в первом , то нужно заполнить для этой переменно пустым значением 0 или NA.

```
a <- data.table(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(43,56,76,34,12))

b <- data.table(c(1,3,5,6), c(33,21,84,25))
```

Для наглядности приведу пример того , что должно получится в итоговом фрейме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При работе с `data.table` удобно исопльзовать функцию `merge`. В данном случае нам понадобится указать параметр `all = TRUE`, чтобы получить поведение аналогичное FULL JOIN.

```r
> res <- merge(a, b, by = c("V1"), all = TRUE)
> res
   V1 V2.x V2.y
1:  1   43   33
2:  2   56   NA
3:  3   76   21
4:  4   34   NA
5:  5   12   84
6:  6   NA   25
```

Заполнить пропущенные значнеия можно с помощью функции `setnafill`.

```r
> setnafill(res, cols = c("V2.x", "V2.y"), fill = 0)
> res
   V1 V2.x V2.y
1:  1   43   33
2:  2   56    0
3:  3   76   21
4:  4   34    0
5:  5   12   84
6:  6    0   25
```

Обратите внимание, что `setnafill` изменяет таблицу «на месте», аналогично другим функциям в пакете `data.table` с префиксом `set`.